# Why is this inner loop executed n + 1 times?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Here's the algorithm in pseudo code:

```
Algorithm(T[1..n])
    d = ∞
    for i = 1 to n
        for j = 1 to n
            if i != j and |T[i] - T[j]| < d
                d = |T[i] - T[j]|
    return d
```

The outer loop is executed n times, I know this, but why does it say in my text book the inner loop is excited n + 1 times? It's hard to understand.

Comment: Re: "why does it say in my text book the inner loop is excited n + 1 times": Are you saying that, according to your textbook, the line `d = |T[1] - T[j]` is executed exactly *n* + 1 times regardless of what the elements of *T* are? If it really says that, then please throw your book in the recycle bin and buy a different one. It's easy to choose *T* such that the innermost line is executed fewer times (for example, if *T* starts with `1 1 ...`, then that line is executed only once) or more times (for example, if *T* is `10 0 3 5 6` then that line is executed seven times).

Comment: What is T exactly?

Comment: If you don't understand what *T* is, then why did you post the question "why does it say in my text book the inner loop is excited n + 1 times?" instead of a more basic question like "What is *T*?"

Comment: I have a faint idea what T is, but I just wanna be sure, but thank you for your first answer.

Comment: It looks to me like both outer and inner loops run n-1 iterations, O(n^2).

Comment: @lara Why n-1? T is of n length no?

Comment: My eye jumped to the initial value of 1.  Many languages use zero-based array indexes, and a loop to n means a loop "up to n", but you're right, it depends on the language.  In either case, the scalar makes no difference for the time complexity

Comment: @lara but if my loop starts at 1 it still means it will execute n-1 times, no?

Comment: @user2426691 - To recap: the algorithm-describing language in the question is ambiguous. from 1 to n might mean n iterations (it probably does), and it might mean n-1.  What is certain is that the bounds on both inner and outer loop are the same, so (unless it's the strangest language ever) the inner and outer loop execute the same number of iterations.  A textbook stating otherwise, as the question asserts, is almost certainly in need of a reprint.  For stating complexity, we typically only care about the order of the polynomial.  So (n+1)^2 or n^2 or (n-1)^2 are all O(n^2)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your book says that the inner loop is execute `n+1` times.
As given, it appears to be an error.  The inner loop is execute `n` times, and each of those executions consists of `n` iterations.

To be clear, the inner loop is `for j = 1 to n` and its body.  That `for` is restarted `n` times; the *body* is executed `n` times for each of those starts.

```
for i = 1 to n
    // we reach this point n times
    for j = 1 to n
        // we reach this point n*n times
        if i != j and  // we reach this point n*(n-1) times
                       |T[i] - T[j]| < d
            // the number of times we reach this point depends on the values of T
            d = |T[i] - T[j]|
```

Comment: You say: we reach this point n*(n-1) times, but why n-1 not n+1?

Comment: We get to the `if` only `n` times, and we have to get there to get here; it's not *possible* to get to this point `n+1` times.

Comment: It's `n-1` because the `if` condition bypasses exactly 1 of the `n` iterations.